# How can i add all videos from youtube playlist as post?

Tags: plugins, youtube

I want to add 200 videos from YouTube playlist to my WordPress blog. Each video iframe add as each post to particular category. I searched many plugins but that's not meet my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Youtube playlist have a xml strema, RSS feed.

You can parse this and create post via `wp_insert_post()` and add as content the URL to the video. Publish this and you have wich each new video from the playlist a new post.

The best way is, that you write a custom plugin. But you can aslo use a auto publisher plugin for feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

- [Fetch the playlist XML](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_a_playlist). Use that as import file.
- Write a custom importer. Look at the native WXR importer to see how that works. Should be very similar.